# create iso from windows xp 64 setup files

Tags: windows-xp, images, bootable-media, burning

hi i have the following windows xp 64 bit files(starting with uppercase letter are folders):
Amd64, Docs,I386,Support,autorun,readme,setup,...

how can i create the iso from these files? it keeps asking for boot image file?

i try to burn it(as bootable disc) into cd, but it asks for boot image? where is boot image file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like kind of a pain, but it can be done:

http://www.howtohaven.com/system/createwindowssetupdisk.shtml

Comment: You're linking to another How To site? Does HTG know about this?

Comment: What did we learn about link only answers?

Comment: @eight I was gonna summarize, but man, that sounds complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with something along the same lines. Check out the solution I got

[Why won't Windows XP 64 install on my machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/127649/why-wont-windows-xp-64-install-on-my-machine)