# Why won't Windows XP 64 install on my machine?

Tags: windows, boot, installation

I have a  HP xw8200 workstation and would like to install Windows XP 64 bit on it. The problem I seem to be having is when I reboot the machine and try to boot from the CD, nothing happens. It seems that the CD drive is not being located or does not execute my CD to start the install.

I already checked to verify that I can install Windows XP 64bit on my machine and also ensured I have the right bios and drivers for the install, only that the boot just does not take place. Anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?

#### Links:

- [HP xw8200 Workstation Specs](http://www.hp.com/workstations/pws/xw8200/xw8200.pdf)
- [HP - Microsoft® Windows® XP Professional x64 Edition and HP Workstations](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/cache/286710-0-0-225-121.html)
- [HP - Microsoft® Windows® XP Professional x64 Edition Frequently Asked Questions](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/cache/286707-0-0-225-121.html)

Comment: can you read the CD/DVD you are trying to boot from on another system? Will it boot on another system?

Comment: I can read the CD/DVD on another machine, and even the very same but when I try to run it on either machine, I run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially, I downloaded and copied Windows XP 64 bit Trial to CDs and DVDs

How did you copy to the CD?  If you simply copied the iso file to the CD/DVD, or even copy the files from one CD to another it will not create a bootable disk.

If you have an iso file, you need to burn the image using a utility.

You can use [ImageBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) or [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) or [BootCDCC](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/downloads-free-software.htm) (or loads more)

Comment: Thanks sgmoore! I used all 3 and BootCDCC did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the BIOS setting for boot order? Often times a computer can be set to check possible boot devices in different orders.

Having the computer immediately boot from the hard drive instead of checking the CD drive then the hard drive is faster. You save the time to spin up the CD to check for an often unneeded bootable CD. In this case, you obviously need it.

If this might be the case -- I.e. you can't boot other CD too -- then you should be able to change this from the BIOs. You're post indicated you know how to get in to the BIOs. Once in there, search for something like boot order or boot media.

Comment: I have CD at the top of boot order, what happens is it stalls for a couple of seconds and then continues booting from Hard drive.